# PHP init being called twice?

Tags: php, class, zend-framework

I have the following class

```
 class CLG_Container_Main_Schedule extends CLG_Container_Main
 {
     protected $_box = 'schedule';

     public function __construct($calendar=null)
     {
         parent::__construct($this->_box);
         $this->init();
     }


     public function init()
     {  
         $this->setTitle('Schedule');

         $html = '<div id="schedule_time">';
         for( $h = 5; $h < 24; $h++ )
         {
             for( $m=0; $m <60; $m += 15 )
             {
                 $time = str_pad($h, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' . str_pad($m, 2, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
                 $time_id = str_pad($h, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . str_pad($m, 2, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
                 $html .= '<div class="schedule_time" time="' . $time_id . '">' . $time . '</div>';
             }
         }
         $html .= '</div>';
         $this->setContent($html);
     }


     public function render()
     {
         return parent::render();
     }
 }
```

For some reason, the class function is being called twice, because I get two instances of the $html I am creating. The weird thing is that I have another container class and that also calls init() in the constructor, but that one is only called once.

What am I missing? When I delete init() from the constructor, the init() is called some how, and everything works fine.

Thanks

Comment: Does `CLG_Container_Main` also call `init()` in it's constructor?

Comment: fire up a debugger and set a breakpoint in the constructor. Look at the stack trace to see what is calling it.

Comment: Yes, the CLG_Container_Main also calls init(), but that should run the init that is in Main? Or do I need to give them different names?

Answer (score 2):

Since `init()` is called from the `parent::__construct(..)` you do not need to call it from the child constructor. PHP will call the correct `init()` method when the class is created.

You have verified this when you removed the call to `init` from your child class and everything worked as expected.

You can verify this by running this simple example that reflects more or less what is going on in your code.

```
<?php

class AParent {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->init();
    }

    public function init() {
        echo "init parent\n";   
    }
}


class AChild extends AParent {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function init(){
        echo "init child\n" ;
    }
}

new AParent(); // Calls init from AParent
new AChild(); // Calls init from AChild
```

Comment: Pretty much what I was eluding too in comments.